# Connection refused while using sstableLoader to stream data to cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, bulkloader

I am trying to stream some sstables to Cassandra cluster using SStableLoader utility. I am getting a streaming error. Here is the stack.

```
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
18:05:04.058 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.i.s.m.MetadataSerializer - Load metadata for /path/new/xyz/search/xyz-search-ka-1
18:05:04.073 [main] INFO  o.a.c.io.sstable.SSTableReader - Opening /path/new/xyz/new/xyz_search/search/xyz_search-search-ka-1 (330768 bytes)
Streaming relevant part of /path/new/xyz/xyz_search/search/xyz_search-search-ka-1-Data.db to [/10.XXX.XXX.XXX, /10.XXX.XXX.XXX, /10.XXX.XXX.XXX, /10.XXX.XXX.XXX, /10.XXX.XXX.XXX]
18:05:04.411 [main] INFO  o.a.c.streaming.StreamResultFuture - [Stream #ed3a0cd0-fd25-11e5-8509-63e9961cf787] Executing streaming plan for Bulk Load
Streaming relevant part of /path/xyz-search-ka-1-Data.db to [/10.XXX.XXX.XXX, /10.XXX.XXX.XXX, /10.XXX.XXX.XXX, /10.XXX.XXX.XXX, /10.XXX.XXX.XXX]
17:22:44.175 [main] INFO  o.a.c.streaming.StreamResultFuture - [Stream #0327a9e0-fd20-11e5-b350-63e9961cf787] Executing streaming plan for Bulk Load
17:22:44.177 [StreamConnectionEstablisher:1] INFO  o.a.c.streaming.StreamSession - [Stream #0327a9e0-fd20-11e5-b350-63e9961cf787] Starting streaming to /10.XX.XX.XX
17:22:44.177 [StreamConnectionEstablisher:1] DEBUG o.a.c.streaming.ConnectionHandler - [Stream #0327a9e0-fd20-11e5-b350-63e9961cf787] Sending stream init for incoming stream
17:22:44.183 [StreamConnectionEstablisher:2] INFO  o.a.c.streaming.StreamSession - [Stream #0327a9e0-fd20-11e5-b350-63e9961cf787] Starting streaming to /10.XX.XX.XX
17:22:44.183 [StreamConnectionEstablisher:2] DEBUG o.a.c.streaming.ConnectionHandler - [Stream #0327a9e0-fd20-11e5-b350-63e9961cf787] Sending stream init for incoming stream
17:23:47.191 [StreamConnectionEstablisher:2] ERROR o.a.c.streaming.StreamSession - [Stream #0327a9e0-fd20-11e5-b350-63e9961cf787] Streaming error occurred
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:458) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:450) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadConnectionFactory.createConnection(BulkLoadConnectionFactory.java:62) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.createConnection(StreamSession.java:236) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler.initiate(ConnectionHandler.java:79) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.start(StreamSession.java:223) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator$StreamSessionConnector.run(StreamCoordinator.java:208) [cassandra-all-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
17:23:47.202 [StreamConnectionEstablisher:2] DEBUG o.a.c.streaming.ConnectionHandler - [Stream #0327a9e0-fd20-11e5-b350-63e9961cf787] Closing stream connection handler on /10.XXX.XXX.XXX
17:23:47.205 [StreamConnectionEstablisher:1] ERROR o.a.c.streaming.StreamSession - [Stream #0327a9e0-fd20-11e5-b350-63e9961cf787] Streaming error occurred
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:458) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:450) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadConnectionFactory.createConnection(BulkLoadConnectionFactory.java:62) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.createConnection(StreamSession.java:236) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler.initiate(ConnectionHandler.java:79) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.start(StreamSession.java:223) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator$StreamSessionConnector.run(StreamCoordinator.java:208) [cassandra-all-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Also the machine where I am running the sstableloader is out of the cassandra cluster.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging a little more, found that sstableloader also uses port 7000 while streaming sstables to cassandra cluster. My local machine did not have access to port 7000 on the machines on cassandra cluster. That's why i was getting connection time out exception.

Anyone who encounters this make sure that your machine from where you are running the sstableloader has access to port 9160,7000 and 9042 of all the casssandra nodes you are trying to stream to.

Answer (score 0):

> DEBUG o.a.c.streaming.ConnectionHandler - [Stream #0327a9e0-fd20-11e5-b350-63e9961cf787] Closing stream connection handler on /10.XXX.XXX.XXX

Hint: I suspect the machine 10.xxx.xxx.xxx is under heavy load. Worth checking the `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` file on this machine to narrow down the root cause